# Virtualise old windows hard drive on a mac

Tags: windows, mac, external-hard-drive, multi-boot

I have an old Windows IDE 3.5" hard drive that I'd like to boot up and run on my mac (not permanently, maybe just once or twice). I do not want to simply check the contents with an adapter - I have one of those.
What would be the quickest/least complicated free way of doing this?

Comment: That depends on a whole lot of things. For starters, was this HDD previously connected the a MAC and running windows or was it oin other hardware. (Windows does not like moving between hardware. Sometimes it works. Sometimes you have to sysprep on the old system before moving to the new system). Also, which Mac. Plenty of different versions, from good old 68k to powerPC to intel CPUs. In short, we need a lot more informationt o be able to answer this.

Comment: Also, Windows doesn't like booting from an external enclosure, even if you can persuade the Mac it even wants to try booting it. IDE suggests it may be old, XP or so, which would be older than WinToGo. I'd be satisfied with just scavenging the data, I very much doubt you will succeed in booting it, without trying to migrate it to Parallels etc.

Comment: @Tetsujin  Regarding booting externally, you say it isn't liked, do you mean just by USB? 'cos what about if he had an eSATA port, so maybe an IDE-SATA adaptor and booting that way? Also he already knows about scaveging data 'cos he mentioned adaptor by which he probably means USB-IDE adaptor.

Comment: You might get it to at least attempt to boot using ReFind - https://superuser.com/questions/16251/how-to-boot-windows-xp-on-a-mac-from-an-external-drive - but the Windows drive is going to struggle to get through the initial boot process because it doesn't know what the hardware is.